# How to run Android Applications in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

my system is **Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010)** with newly installed **Ubuntu** and i am having trouble because of **64 bit** system. on running Android Application i am getting error:

```
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt
Hint: On 64-bit systems, make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Error R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

before this error i was getting adb not found error. i tried to install

```
ia32-lib
```

but unable to install. :(

Comment: It is `ia32-libs` not `ia32-lib`, so that's most likely the reason your install attempt failed.

Comment: oh sorry my fault..i wrote wrong it was **ia32-libs**
after running this:
rahul@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
it is saying you held broken packages

Comment: then fix these broken packages first.

Comment: that's the problem...it is not fixing. :(

Comment: [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136394/cannot-install-ia32-libs
almost every solution !

Answer (score 0):

I also installed on linux 64 bits the android sdk, eclipse and all things necessary to android programmer, in this case the fedora 17 64 bits, I lost a full day to make all works fine because the android sdk for linux is only supported in 32 bits and for works in 64 bits I needed install very much libs... so hard :/, I recommend you uses the 32 bits if you want programme on linux :)

and in my vision, the ubuntu 32 bits is the better plataform to developer to android, how to I need make androoid and ios apps, i'm working on mac but the ubuntu is better if you only programmer on android :)

---

unfortunately do not remember all the libs I used and steps I went to make it work :(

Comment: @Raahul maybe better :), in linux is not like windows on the differences between 32 and 64 bits are not a guarantee of better performance.

Comment: @ademar111190 who told you that?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com my conclusion :), the only reason to use a linux 64 bits today is if you have more of 4gb of ram, it's because the majority of programs on linux be compiled on 32 bits and if you use in 64 bits you need a compability layer to run 32 bits prograns and because this you loses more time then win using 64 bits word on bus. I can be wrong but it's my impression when I use linux 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: The performance boost would be noticeable in **computing hungry processes**, but if all you use is `ls` or `mc` or `vim` then yes, there's no much **performance** benefits visible. Still, it got nothing to do with OS being linux.

Comment: it's true, not is because is linux, it's because the programs around there be 32 bits, only this. on mac and on windows the majority of programs already adapted to 64 bits only this, is not because be or not be linux.